# i want to open a pdf files found on the wamp server, the pdf files will change every day but their name will be the same

Tags: android, pdf, caching, android-intent

the program is to open PDF files found on the server, PDF files will changes every day but their name will be the same.

when i opened the program for the first time every thing is fine, but when i changed the PDF file and open the program again it still show me the old PDF file

**Code:**

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,                                            
    Uri.parse(Constants.PDF_ROOT_URL+"/portfolio/2.pdf")); 
    startActivity(myIntent);
```

Please, how I can solve this?

Comment: Please write some proper steps and the cases that help us to understand the actual problem.

Comment: i add additional information about the problem.

Comment: `it still show me the old PDF file` Who/what is 'it'?

Comment: the pdf viewer show the old pdf, even when i change the pdf file.
i thank the old files remains in the cache.

Comment: Which pdf viewer app? Try other ones.

Comment: the default PDF viewer, please any help?